# How to set up a WCF client using wsDualHttpBinding in code?

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I have a need to connect to a WCF service I wrote without having to deploy an app.config for the client application I'm writing. However, I've been having a very difficult time trying to figure out how to set up things from the client side in code. This is as far as I've gotten... does anyone have any ideas what I need to do to get this to work? I'd really appreciate it.

This is the code I've got so far:

```
    String baseAddress = "http://localhost/CommService";

    WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
    binding.Name = "WSDualHttpBinding_ICommService";
    binding.ClientBaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    binding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
    binding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);

    InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);
    client = new CommServiceClient(context, "WSDualHttpBinding_ICommService");
    client.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
```

And this is my client app's app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_ICommService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:05"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/CommService/"
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_ICommService"
            contract="Services.ICommService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_ICommService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily achieve what you want. See code below :

```
 Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/CommService");
 WSDualHttpBinding wsd = new WSDualHttpBinding();
 EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(baseAddress, EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("localhost"));
 client  = new CommServiceClient(new InstanceContext(this), wsd, ea);
```

Let me explain a bit :

- first we create an instance of a WSDualHttpBinding with the default settings (those are the exact ones the generated app.config has). If you want to modify any of the settings, you can modify them trough the exposed properties.
- then we create an EndPointAddress with th desired URL and identity. No need to link it with a binding because we will link all of them in the Service Client constructor.
- lastly we create the Service Client. One of the contructor overloads allows us to specify a Binding and an Endpoint Address.
- in general every element available in the app.config file has an associated Class in .NET code and every attribute or child element has an associated Property in the specified class.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! It was driving me crazy, haha.