# ServicePoint in WCF fails to bind IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, networking

I have the following code

```
 WSDualHttpBinding oBinding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
            oBinding.Security.Mode = WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None;
            oBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.MessageCredentialType.None;
            oBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;

            oBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
            oBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
            oBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 7);

            EndpointAddress oEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(oDataSource.wcfURL);

            var localIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.121");
            ServicePoint servicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(oDataSource.wcfURL));
            servicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate =
                            (sp, rm, retryCount) =>
                            {
                                return new IPEndPoint(localIpAddress, 80);
                            };

            DuplexChannelFactory<IBSPubSubService> oChannelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IBSPubSubService>(new InstanceContext(this), oBinding, oEndpoint);

            oPubSubClient = oChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            oPubSubClient.Faulted += new EventHandler(WcfFaultedListener);
            oPubSubClient.Opened += new EventHandler(WcfOpenListener);
```

The goal is to use specific IP address and port to connect to WCF service. However, when I try to use the code above, seems like I cannot create a channel to wcf anymore. Removing servicepoint would work but without it I would not be able to select sepicific IP that I want to use in case of multiple NIC. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: are you tring to give that `IP address` as the  `END Point` , then you need to create the `EndpointAddress` , for more info  take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497209/how-to-set-up-a-wcf-client-using-wsdualhttpbinding-in-code)

Comment: I am trying to use the IP address as the outgoing IP address of the client in case of multiple NIC.